# NoReverseMatch at /music/ 'music' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

```
Error during template rendering

In template
```

C:\Users\Pranay\Desktop\website\music\templates\music\index.html, error at line 5

'music' is not a registered namespace

this is the template code with the error:

```
{% if all_albums %}
<h3>here are all my albums</h3>
<ul>
    {% for album in all_albums %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{ album.album_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
<h3>you dont have any albums</h3>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
# /music/
 url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),

 # /music/<album_id>/
 url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail,name='detail'),

 # /music/<album_id>/favorite
 url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite,name='favorite'),
]
```

i have added my urls.py code

Comment: show your app urls

Answer (score 5):

If you use the namespace `music` in `{% url 'music:detail album.id %}` then you either need to include the `app_name` in `music/urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
...
]
```

Or specify the namespace when including the music urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^music/', include('music.urls', namespace='music'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Django 2.0 onwards I found that your `music/urls.py` would look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    path('<int:album_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```